# Get Sum of Exchange Mailbox Statistics

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

I'm trying to get the sum of the `TotalItemSize` for an Exchange database using the command

`Get-MailboxStatistics -Database MBX07 | Measure-Object -Sum TotalItemSize`

The command works perfectly fine in the Windows PowerShell ISE but if I run it in an Exchange EMS (both are on my local machine) I get errors for every mailbox in the database that say

> Measure-Object : Input object "8.518 MB (8,932,049 bytes)" is not
>   numeric.

The output in the ISE where the command works looks like

```
Count    : 174
Average  : 
Sum      : 203481256406
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property : TotalItemSize
```

It's an Exchange 2010 SP1 server running on Windows Server 2008 R2 and I'm running Windows 8.1 64bit

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was run from my EMC on my server.

```
Get-MailboxStatistics -Database MBX07 | ForEach-Object {[Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ByteQuantifiedSize]::Parse($_.TotalItemSize)} | Measure-Object -sum
```

`TotalItemSize` is of type `Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ByteQuantifiedSize` so we use its method `Parse` to get a value we can put into `-sum`

More on this [here](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/10/08/pstip-parsing-exchange-size-strings/)

**BONUS**

You can try this which will output the Sum in MB

```
Get-MailboxStatistics -Database MBX07 | ForEach-Object {
     ([Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ByteQuantifiedSize]::Parse($_.TotalItemSize)).ToMb()
     } | Measure-Object -sum
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks for the help and the link with the extra info.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more PowerShell native way, instead of calling a .NET method with ::

Get-Mailbox -Database "DB1" | Get-MailboxStatistics | ForEach-Object { $_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToGb() } | Measure-Object -sum

Answer (score 0):

**Useful for large servers, for all databases and in Giga Byte**

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSet Unlimited | Get-MailboxStatistics | ForEach-Object {
     ([Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ByteQuantifiedSize]::Parse($_.TotalItemSize)).ToGb()
     } | Measure-Object -sum
```