# How get TotalItemSize per database

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I want to get the TotalItemSize per database on Exchange 2013.
I have tried this command to count the mailbox per database but I don't kjown how to get the TotalItemSize per database

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize 10 | Get-MailboxStatistics |  select-object DisplayName,database,{$_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()} | Group-Object database
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455581/get-sum-of-exchange-mailbox-statistics).

Or try

```
get-mailboxdatabase | % { Get-Mailbox -database $_.name -ResultSize 10 | Get-MailboxStatistics |  select-object DisplayName,`
database,@{l=size;e={$_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()}} | Measure-Object -sum size }
```

And yes, this code does only count 10 Mailboxes, as per -resultSize

There is also a direct cmdlet for getting the totalsize of a database:

```
Get-MailboxDatabase -Status | select Name, DatabaseSize
```

Comment: This is not the result I want. I need the sum of TotalItemSize per database

Comment: Changed it to a measurement per database.